# sphinx-quickstart not working on WinXP

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a Python(x,y) distribution installed on winxp, which includes the sphinx module for making documentation.

The first step in setting up sphinx is running the 'sphinx-quickstart' command at the prompt. It's just not responding. Nothing happens when I type that in.

I checked the module. It seems to be installed properly. Am I missing some tool that is required to run it on the DOS prompt. I tried doing it in the cygwin terminal too and it's not working there either.

Thanks

PS: Sphinx can be imported as a module in a Python shell. Is it possible to use sphinx entirely through the Python shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, some of the files in the Python/Scripts folders are applications, not simply scripts. And most of these applications are not meant for DOS modes.

So I had to reinstall some packages, including setuptools and sphinx, via distributions specifically for Windows, which wasn't the case when I installed everything from the Python(x,y) distribution.

This works fine, but with a few kinks.